# How can I capture an image from a Live video using OpenCV 3 & Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, video

I want to capture an image from a live video and then compare the taken image with an image already exists in library. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture live video by using:

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
```

Then, you can get every single frame (image) by

```
while(True)
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   # Perform your comparison here, 
   # between (frame) and your image
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```